# How to import Postgres (binary or text) dump file into Spark or HDFS?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, sqoop

I would like to use a Postgres (binary or text) dump file in Spark and wonder how to import it? I know that we can use Sqoop to import Postgres into HDFS, and that i can access the HDFS from Spark, but what if I just have the dump file? Do I have to restore it into a Postgres database first? I would prefer not to.

Comment: Can you help clarify how that command is used in the context of my question? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `pg_restore --data-only -t my_table db.dump` you should get tab-separated text with some comments and a few extra commands, it would be simple to filter out everything you don't want and write that file to HDFS.

Then it's a matter of reading that file as a CSV file from Spark or MapReduce.